# C++ array like class element definition

Tags: c++, arrays, oop, operators

I want to create a smaller vector class for a microcontroller.

In the normal vector class, your can do something like:

```
myvector[1] = 100;
```

How is it possible to achieve such an assignment in a class?

I tried this:

```
template<typename T>
class Vector
{
 private:
    T* content;
 public:
    T* operator[](unsigned int);
};
template <typename T>
T* Vector::operator[](unsigned int i)
{
    return &content[i];
}
```

But, that throws errors, and it would also not be a nice solution.

So what should I do?

Answer (score 2):

In the case you display above, you are returning a pointer to the value, which is presumably why you are having difficulties. Consider returning a reference instead:

```
T& operator[](unsigned int);
```

Comment: &content[i]  doesn't work with it, i don't know why. Visual Studio says "Initial Value of reference to non-const must be an lvalue"

Comment: Ahh, got it. To define a reference, you don't need the &operator.
You can just do:
T& myref = content[i];

Comment: @DLCom You just just `return content[i];` in your modified `T& operator[](unsigned int);`. I'd also suggest replacing `unsigned int` by [`std::size_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t).